# how to create an array without objects initialized to null or 0?

Tags: c#, .net

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[500000];
```

initializes buffer with 0 values. As it is a buffer, I dont want any initialization, is it possible in C# as in C?

Comment: *I dont want any initialization* What does that mean, you want the `buffer` to be `null`? `0` is the default value for `byte`, what would you actually want to happen?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov He wants an uninitialized array... So an array filled with whatever was present in that area of memory... (like C `malloc`) I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Just curious why it matters? If there is no meaningful data in the buffer yet, what difference does it make whether it's all zeroes or random bytes?

Comment: i have found :            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(500000);

Comment: Instead of avoiding initiallization, perhaps you should look at *reusing* buffers by using [BufferManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible... Even [FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx) that doesn't run constructors:

> Because the new instance of the object is initialized to zero and no constructors are run, the object might not represent a state that is regarded as valid by that object.

Note that if you want unmanaged (memory taken from the OS that isn't GC-managed), *that* can be allocated without zeroing it, but it wouldn't be a `byte[]`.

Comment: I just found a question that points out some differences between "reserved" and "committed" memory when initializing 2D arrays in .NET. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039379/why-doesnt-net-allocate-memory-when-initialize-a-2d-array. Do you think this extends to regular, 1D arrays?

Comment: @Asad Yes, just checked... But if you are thinking of using unsafe code with `fixed` to access the memory before it is initialized, I don't think it works :-) I think that it is the OS that allocates the memory when requested (and cleans it), not the .NET .

Comment: Right, so this means the OP doesn't need to worry about paying initialization costs with their large array (at least on the Windows .NET VM). That is the only reason I can think of for the OP wanting to do this.

Comment: @Asad I'm not sure of this... There is the possibility that GC doesn't returns blocks of memory that aren't used anymore to the OS... it probably keeps them and so the first init is OS-based, while next ones are CLR done.

Answer (score 1):

A way in C# to do what `malloc` does in C is to use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` in an `unsafe` context:

```
unsafe
{
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(50000 * sizeof(int));
    int* values = (int*)ptr;

    // lists uninitialized ints
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(values[i]);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Note the warnings in the method's page: it exposes LocalAlloc which applications aren't supposed to use. It is also *slower* than heap allocation methods

Comment: In fact, the OP should probably use [BufferManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to allocate reusable buffers from one initial block of memory rather than allocate new buffers, even if they aren't initialized

Answer (score 0):

Fill it with random numbers or use `DllImport` and `VirtualAlloc` from Win32 API.

Comment: From [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa366887.aspx): *Reserves or commits a region of memory within the virtual address space of a specified process. **The function initializes the memory it allocates to zero**, unless MEM_RESET is used.*, and for *MEM_RESET*: *Indicates that data in the memory range specified by lpAddress and dwSize is no longer of interest.* so it can't be used on first call.

Comment: Ok, there is `GlobalAlloc + GlobalLock` to alloc uninitialized memory. It can be used as source of "random" memory. I suspect the author want to catch values in RAM from other processes...

Comment: There is even the `HeapAlloc` to do it.