# Copy a ReadOnlySpan to a Span in one pass

Tags: c#, performance, memory, f#

All guidelines seem to boil down to creating a new `Span`, initialized by an array of a given type. This involves an extra pass and an extra zeroing of the array.

I'm wondering if there's a way to allocate some memory for a `Span` (like `Span -> 'a[] -> 'Span<'a>`), but then with a `ReadOnlySpan` as source. I currently have two approaches (`str` is a string, `len` is the string length):

Approach 1 involves an extra pass:

```
let roSpan = str.AsSpan()
let writeSpan = Span(Array.zeroCreate<char> len)
roSpan.CopyTo writeSpan
```

Approach 2 has one pass too few (this turns a ReadOnlySpan into a read/write Span, dangerous stuff):

```
let roSpan = str.AsSpan()
let writeSpan = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(&MemoryMarshal.GetReference roSpan, len)
```

I've searched for both C# and F# solutions but couldn't find a good answer. One approach might be with `MemoryPool`, but that seems to be overkill for the simple "copy this into something read-/writeable".

*<sup>tagged this both C# and F# as I don't really mind an answer in either language</sup>*

Comment: The simplest way to copy a read-only span to a span would be `let writeSpan = roSpan.ToArray().AsSpan()`, however from the [reference source](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/ReadOnlySpan.cs#L384) it appears `ReadOnlySpan<T>.ToArray()` allocates the array then copies into it which first initializes the array with zeros - which you don't want.

Comment: @dbc, exactly. I know there's an IL instruction that can allocate an array, but not initialize it. With `Span`, I hoped there would be something like `Span.Init` or whatever, but I think it has something to do with the ownership-rules: spans don't own their memory. Hence it must be initialized _outside_ the span itself.

Comment: In fact I don't think it is possible to allocate an array on the heap without zeroing it in .Net (other than maybe the IL instruction you mention -- I didn't know about that), see [how to create an array without objects initialized to null or 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30319291).  One alternative would be to rent and dispose a `MemoryPool<T>.Shared` array as you propose.

Comment: Another would be to do a `stackalloc` for smaller arrays while still doing an array allocation for larger arrays.  `stackalloc` doesn't zero the memory which would meet your requirements.  In c# this would look like `Span<char> writeSpan = roSpan.Length < 256 ? stackalloc char[roSpan.Length] : new char[roSpan.Length];`, however I believe (but have not checked) this can't be done in f# without having to write unsafe code, see [Add a safe stackalloc function that returns a Span #720](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/720).

Comment: @dbc, I've briefly considered `stackalloc`, but dismissed it on the grounds that I cannot control the size of the input for the general case. And we all know stack is small. For strings I can get what I want with `String.Create`, which allocates + initializes in one go and is much faster (some 30% seen on BDN) and uses 2x less mem than `createCharArray().AsSpan()` and then loop over it and passing it to `new String`. But that's for just strings, I don't know if for other types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things have changed since I asked this question. From .NET 5.0 onwards, there's now a way to skip the zero-init of the array, which allows for a read-only span to be copied to a read-write span, without the extra pass over the array for the zeroing:

```ml
let roSpan = str.AsSpan()
let writeSpan = Span(GC.AllocateUninitializedArray<char> len)   // skip zero-init for large arrays
roSpan.CopyTo writeSpan
```